# Azure Function V2 exception logs missing stack trace

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a V2 Function deployed which has an unhandled exception. I would expect (and think it was in V1) to see the stack trace and line number in the error log but instead all I get is:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: MyFunction. MyProjectNameToCall: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is there some configuration I need to set to be able to see this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you looking to find the error logs? Log streaming? Application Insights? Somewhere else?

Comment: I've got application insights enabled, it's viewable from there and in the Function portal 'monitor' section

Comment: So your question is about the streaming logs under the code editor in the Azure Portal?

Comment: The stack trace is not in the streaming logs either (its the same message in streaming, insights etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realised my mistake. The logging in the monitor section of the Functions only displays trace information and when I was looking in Application Insights I was only looking at traces.

If I view 'exceptions' (seems quite obvious now!) in Application Insights then I can see the stack trace and line numbers.

Comment: Hint: In Azure Functions, there is a shortcut to App Insights. The pre-populated query restricts displayed to three common columns for trace and exception. None of them contain actual exception information containing files and line numbers. Full query with only exceptions will have all necessary information.